# Controlling for overall economic factors and seasonality in a time series?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, seasonality

Let's say I have a time series of retail clothing sales. I want to see the sales data adjusted for several factors - overall economic trend and seasonality.

I can do a seasonal decomposition with the assumption of an annual seasonality and linear trend, and use the residuals to see my time series adjusted for those factors. Or, I can use a control group (the overall retail clothing sales across my country) and subtract that out to get a time series presumably adjusted for trend and seasonality (and other factors).

I could also do seasonal decomposition on the entire national data set, to determine national trends and seasonality and subtract that from my regional sales data.

What are the differences between these three methods, and what would be the proper way to do this?

Comment: There's probably a whole lot more potential approaches than those listed that could be used.  I've used Fourier basis functions to describe annual cyclic seasonality with additional trend components, and have also used Kalman filter approaches in the past.  I've seen other people use month of year / week of month / day of week regressor factors.  I would recommend refining the question to elaborate more on what specific behaviors you're looking for in the model as well as the predictive horizon on which you aim to employ it (how far out are you looking in time)

Comment: @T3am5hark thanks - is there a specific resource you would recommend for this? I'm looking at this from a basic 'dumb' perspective - business leaders want to see how their clothing sales are when you account for the overall industry trend, and when you account for seasonal variations. I guess the seasonal variation part is the difficult one - how do I determine the number of seasonal components there are in the data? You could argue there might be a daily trend, weekly trend, monthly trend, quarterly trend, and annual trend.

Comment: This one isn't bad if you want to go the Fourier route - using a "log Fourier" decomposition of aggregate demand with 4-8 harmonics of an annual fundamental frequency has given me very good results in the past for modeling slowly-varying seasonal demand.  Holidays can be tricky as they are more "impulsive" in behavior but can generally be handled with specific indicator variables and/or lead/lag effects.

http://www.le.ac.uk/users/dsgp1/COURSES/LEIMETZ/FOURIER.pdf

Comment: Using day/week/month indicator variables with a log-linear model is arguably a little easier to implement, but can be prone to overfitting on noisy data.  Using a penalized fit (like Ridge regression) may help to moderate overfitting, but of course you have to use out-of-sample validation to tune the penalty function which can be tricky with time series data.

Comment: Is your time series daily, weekly, or otherwise?  And how much history do you have to work with?

Comment: @T3am5hark Using Ridge regression would be incredibly easy to implement. On the flipside, what do you think of using scipy fast Fourier transform, taking the top n most dominant frequencies, and then subtracting them out?

Comment: @T3am5hark I have bi-weekly data over the course of 20 years, so a decent size.